# ROS 2 on K8s: Multicast fails within same pod, succeeds in different pods

Tags: linux, networking, kubernetes, ros, multicast

Cross-posted from [k8s discuss](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/multicast-fails-within-same-pod-succeeds-in-different-pods/9435).

#### Cluster information:

Kubernetes version: v1.17.1
Cloud being used: bare-metal
Installation method: kubeadm
Host OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server
CNI and version: weave/flannel/kube-router/calico (latest releases of each)
CRI and version: docker/containerd (19.03.5/1.2.10)

## Problem:

I am attempting to bring up a [ROS 2](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/) installation on Kubernetes, ideally using multiple containers in a single pod.  Under the hood, ROS 2 relies upon DDS for communication, which is based upon UDP multicast.

When I bring up a simple pod deployment with two containers in a producer-consumer configuration, the consumer rarely (if ever) receives a message from the producer.  When I bring up two pods, each with a single container the same producer-consumer configuration, the consumer always receives the messages.

#### Surprises

Every once in a while, the consumer will start up and receive messages as expected.

Furthermore, if one logs into the consumer with `kubectl exec -it ros2-1 -c consumer /bin/bash` then runs `/ros_entrypoint.sh ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener`, messages are sometimes received from the producer in the single pod scenario.

### Expected Behavior

Successful messages appear in the logs of the consumer container as:

```
[INFO] [1579805884.017171859] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]
[INFO] [1579805885.017168023] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 2]
[INFO] [1579805886.017025092] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 3]
```

### Actual Behavior

No such log messages are observed from the consumer.

### Steps to Reproduce:

#### Failure within same pod

1. Bring up a kubernetes cluster
2. Apply the following pod definition: ros2-1.yaml

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: ros2-1
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: producer
       image: osrf/ros2:nightly
       args: ["ros2", "run", "demo_nodes_cpp", "talker"]
     - name: consumer
       image: osrf/ros2:nightly
       args: ["ros2", "run", "demo_nodes_cpp", "listener"]
     restartPolicy: Never
   ```
3. Watch for messages from the consumer with `kubectl logs --follow ros2-1 consumer`.

#### Success in different pods

1. Bring up a kubernetes cluster
2. Apply the following pod definition: ros2-2.yaml

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: ros2-2-producer
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: producer
       image: osrf/ros2:nightly
       args: ["ros2", "run", "demo_nodes_cpp", "talker"]
     restartPolicy: Never
   ---
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: ros2-2-consumer
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: consumer
       image: osrf/ros2:nightly
       args: ["ros2", "run", "demo_nodes_cpp", "listener"]
     restartPolicy: Never
   ```
3. Watch for messages from the consumer with `kubectl logs --follow ros2-2-consumer`.

## Questions:

1. What is causing a single pod deployment to fail, but multi pod deployment to succeed?
2. I am unfamiliar with debugging networking issues within the Kubernetes environment, while fairly experienced on bare-metal.  How should I go about investigating this issue under flannel, weave, or kube-router?

Comment: Is your loopback up?

Comment: I tried it on 2 of my clusters and it works. The only difference now I can see between mine and your cluster is Ubuntu version. I will try to run it on your version later and I will let you know.

Comment: Try adding route in pod: `route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev lo` as I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30982079/12201084)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is answered in this [ubuntu.com article:](https://ubuntu.com/blog/exploring-ros-2-with-kubernetes#:%7E:text=Additionally%2C%20ROS%202,able%20to%20communicate.)

> Additionally, ROS 2 does not provide a method for managing ports used by RTPS. For example, a container can not change the standard RTPS discovery port of 7400, nor can a ROS 2 listener select a port other than its default. As a result, port usage can not be coordinated across multiple ROS 2 containers running in the same pod, and these containers generally will not be able to communicate.