# ROS2 galacitc: Failed to find a free participant index for domain

Tags: ros2

I am using ros2 galactic on Ubuntu 20.04 and when running more node I get error, whatever I run I get the same error:

```
1666768083.909628 [0]       ros2: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
1666768083.909821 [0]       ros2: Failed to find a free participant index for domain 0
[ERROR] [1666768083.909895118] [rmw_cyclonedds_cpp]: rmw_create_node: failed to create domain, error Error

>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:108] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'error not set, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-galactic-rcl-3.1.3/src/rcl/node.c:261'

with this new error message:

  'rcl node's rmw handle is invalid, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-galactic-rcl-3.1.3/src/rcl/node.c:413'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
[ERROR] [1666768083.909944183] [rcl]: Failed to fini publisher for node: 1
error creating node: rcl node's rmw handle is invalid, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-galactic-rcl-3.1.3/src/rcl/node.c:413
```

I think that it allows me only to run some number of nodes, but I don't find any file to change that.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to increase the number of MaxAutoParticipantIndex in your config file.

```
<Discovery>
    <ParticipantIndex>auto</ParticipantIndex>
    <MaxAutoParticipantIndex>100</MaxAutoParticipantIndex>
</Discovery>
```

Comment: I experienced the same symptoms as the OP when running ROS2 Galactic with the Husarnet VPN.  Setting the MaxAutoParticipantIndex parameter in the cyclonedds.xml file in my home directory resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Enabeling multicast on loopback could solved your problem.
Here are some instructions:

> route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev lo
> ifconfig lo multicast

[Multicasting on the loopback device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007311/multicasting-on-the-loopback-device)